# Sonata Admin: Let ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN edit entities of all users (ACL)

Tags: symfony, acl, sonata-admin

In SonataAdmin I have granted user a role: ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN

Also I have granted him:  ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_CITY_ADMIN

Unfortunately this user cannot edit City entities created by other users. Any guess how to fix this?

Comment: try granting:  ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN_CITY_EDIT
Doc : http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html#configuration

Comment: I don't have this role. What you wrote is an action, EDIT, not a role.